# Elementary Bayesian probability problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Manufacturer produces TVs probability of a malfunction in TV is $p$. There are 3 different quality checks in the factory with probability of finding malfunction equal to $p_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ every TV goes only through one  quality check and it's assigned to it at random. Later at the retailer warehouse there is another quality check with the probability of finding malfunction equal to $p_0$.

i) find the probability that TV with malfunction will get to the store? (i.e. goes through both checks)

ii) Assuming TV got to the store already what is the probability that it has a malfunction?

I described to events:

$A$- TV gets to the warehouse

$B$- TV lands in the store

Then: $$P(A\cap B)=P(B|A)P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)$$

but $P(A|B)$ is a probability that I goes through the first check if it goes through second check but the second check occurs only if it passes the first one so it must be equal $1$ but then $P(A\cap B) = P(B)$ what makes completely no sense. Later I thought that since these two events occur one after the other it's like throwing a dice twice so they are independent hence $P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A)$ this makes more sense on the other hand it seems like if it passed the first test it should have bigger odds passing second one.

I feel like I have completely no intuition when it comes to this probability problems. Could some one clarify it for me please?

**Edit: By probability of finding malfunction I mean probability of finding malfunction given that particular TV has one.**

Comment: When you say "probability of finding malfunction", do you mean the probability of finding the malfunction, given that there is one, or the probability of finding a malfunction in a uniformly randomly selected TV, irrespective of whether it has a malfunction?

Comment: @joriki given that there is one.

Comment: Thanks. Please clarify the question. The question should stand by itself and not require the comments to be understood.

Comment: Also, since you don't specify a joint distribution for the quality checks, I take it that you're implicitly making independence assumptions. Am I right in thinking that you assume conditional independence of the quality checks, conditional on the TV having a malfunction? (The alternative would be to assume unconditional independence, but that doesn't seem appropriate.) (This, too, should be clarified in the question.)

Comment: @joriki I dont understad what you are askingg for

Comment: @joriki I did not prove that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ what is the definition of independence so I think I must assumed the independence in the second approach to solve this problem. As I said I am lacking on intuition. I would like to see how someone else approaches this problem I am not a math student I am learning it by myself from the lecture script of local university for fun so I had no opportunity to see similar examples.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest that you link to the lecture script. In the current formulation the assumptions aren't clear. I wasn't talking about the independence of $A$ and $B$ but of the various quality checks. Often, when no joint distribution is specified for events, they are implicitly assumed to be independent. In the present case, that assumption doesn't work, since the passing of a quality check makes it more likely that there's no malfunction, and hence that the other quality checks will be passed.

Comment: A reasonable assumption in the present case would be [conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) of the quality checks, conditional on the presence of a malfunction; that is, for TVs that do have a malfunction, the quality checks would independently pass or fail. But without the precise formulation, it's hard to tell whether this is the intended interpretation, so it would be good if you could provide that.

Comment: @joriki The script is in Polish, which might make it hard to understand for most of users, I tried to translate the question directly best I could. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: I think the script would be good to have even in Polish. I assume it contains mathematical notation that everyone can understand. Also, some people might understand enough Polish to also find the text useful.

Comment: @joriki The particular question is plain text no mathematical notation in it. I solved the problem I will post my solution when I am after work or on Saturday.